# tm_symbols: how to control size?

Tags: r, size, tmap

I am new to tmap.
I am working with tm_dots and I want the size of dots to be determined by a numeric variable. So I wrote tm_dots(size="variable"). I would like to control manually the size of the dots specifying breaks. If I use sizes.legend I can modify the dots in the legend, but this is not reflected in the size of the dots on the map.

Notably, the same is easily accomplished with colours:
tm_dots(col="variable",style="fix",breaks = c(45, 60, 75, 90))
But seems to be not available for size. I am wondering why...

thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is your expected outcome? On this context `tmap` treats the `size` as a continous variable, that's why `sizes.legend` only modifies the legend, and not the size of the dots (the `variable` of each point has not changed).

```r
library(sf)

nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc_point <- st_centroid(nc, of_largest_polygon = TRUE)


# Create something in your range
nc_point$variable <- nc_point$NWBIR74/100

library(tmap)

tm_shape(nc_point) +
  tm_dots(size="variable")
```

[image]

```r
tm_shape(nc_point) +
  tm_dots(size="variable",
          sizes.legend = c(0, 45, 60, 75, 90)) +
  tm_layout(title = "Changes only the legend")
```

[image]
The `col` option behaves differently, since it creates categories (i.e. make cuts on the continuous value) and then plots the categories instead the continuous values:

```r
tm_shape(nc_point) +
  tm_dots(col="variable",
          size=2,
          breaks = c(0, 45, 60, 75, 90), pal=hcl.colors(10))
```

[image]

Note the legend. So if you want the size to behave similar to the `col` you may need to categorise it first (via `cuts`) and label the legend using `legend.format`:

```r
# Create cuts, levels are the left limit
nc_point$cat <- cut(nc_point$variable,
  breaks = c(0, 45, 60, 75, 90),
  labels = FALSE
)

tm_shape(nc_point) +
  tm_dots(size = "cat", legend.format = list(fun = function(x) {
    c(45, 60, 75, 90)[x]
  }))
```

[image]

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for this! The last part of your answer is exactly what I need. I think it would be useful in the package to have the choice of plotting dots both continuously and categorically for both colour and size...If I well understood, with colours there is already this option and many others.